# SUM a column of values that whenever a cell is empty gets it from a default column

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sum a column of values but whenever a cell is empty then it sums the value from a default column. Example:

`+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Default |    A    |    B    |    C    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   10    |         |    0    |    4    |
|   10    |         |         |    2    |
|   10    |         |    0    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  TOTAL  |   30    |   10    |   16    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+`

- **A**: All cells are empty so it sums all cells from Default column `10 + 10 + 10 = 30`
- **B**: First and last cell are not empty (it is '0') so it sums `0 + 10 + 0 = 10`
- **C**: Last cell is empty so it grabs the value from Default column: `4 + 2 + 10 = 16`

I've seen similar questions using [FILTER](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23746/sum-column-only-if-another-column-has-an-empty-value) ([another](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43778/summing-a-column-based-on-another-column-in-google-spreadsheet)) and [Matrix multiplication](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50373/google-spreadsheets-sum-cells-from-another-row-based-on-a-cell-value) but I'm just able to sum one or the other, not mix both columns. Should I be using a conditional IF? Can it be done with a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `4` is in D2, please try:

```
=sum(B2:B4)+SUMIF(B2:B4,"",$A2:$A4)
```

in `B5` and copy it across to suit.